# Distorted texture blender

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to apply a texture in a jacket. The unwrapped model is as you can see in this [image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6gh3BVuWnkgah0QDIa8kEEP5HjRw?e=zjjxs9). If I then try to make it fit the jacket shape, it is completly distorted as you can see in this [image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6gh3BVuWnkgah0QDIa8kEEP5HjRw?e=zjjxs9). How can I fix it?

Does anyone know a good tutorial for texturing clothes (Not procedural)?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Maybe sahre your file so that we can try a solution? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots you can download it from here: Name: [Model.rar](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6gh3BVuWnkgah0QDIa8kEEP5HjRw?e=zjjxs9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Follow Active Quads* method:

Select the back or the front of your t-shirt, select a face in your UV, square it manually or with the *UV Squares* addon:

[image]

Keep this face selected so that it's the active one, select all and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quads*:

[image]

It works:

[image]

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't work. Do you have any tutorial where I can see how to use it correctly?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work, do you mean that you don't have the same result or that you don't want this result? There must be some tutorials but I don't know where, but we can speak through discord if you want, join and send me a PM: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: It doesn't work for what I want to do. I want to apply this [texture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6gh3BVuWnkgakoU2-ErAI8GAARtA?e=MrFqPq) but using the "follow active quads" method I get [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6gh3BVuWnkgakoU2-ErAI8GAARtA?e=MrFqPq). The checkered texture you see is only to show how much the texture is distorted.